# Redirect all sub pages to parent home

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have website like `www.example.com` and this page already redirected to `www.newdomain.com`, The rediction rule written in somewhere. not in the root directory.

When I enter `www.example.com/about-us` its redirected to `www.newdomain.com/about-us` and says 404 page not found. I want to redirect all subpages from `example.com` to `example.com` home page.

I used following code but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent/(?!index\.php).+)$ /parent/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Isn't it better to find and fix the redirect? Anyway this new redirect will end with infinite loop (the change needs to be done on newdomain.com, otherwise you will have 2 redirects, one precede the other).

Comment: Can you share your htaccess rules you are using to redirect your old site to the new one?

Comment: First redirect ends processing the other rules. However, you may add a rewrite rule in `newdomain.com` to apply another redirection if you don't have access to modify the current rules.